# Can not retrieve correct message from kafka using Flink

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro, flink-streaming

I'm new to Flink and today I encounter a weird situation.

I run a kafka server, after that I send a message using confluent producer. Using consumer I get the correct message but in the application I can not.
I use this image to set up message broker `confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.1`

I use this to send message to kafka server

```
./kafka-avro-console-producer \
--broker-list localhost:9092 \
--topic test \
--property 
value.schema='{"type":"record","namespace":"com.example.kafka","name":"User","fields": 
[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"age","type":"int"}]}'
```

The message I send is `{"name":"Huy","age":12}`

I use this to listen to message from kafka

```
./kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic test \
--bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

This is my code

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setParallelism(1);
KafkaSource<String> source  = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
            .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
            .setTopics("test")
            .setGroupId("console-consumer-29300")
            .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
            .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
            .build();
    env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "kafka").print();
env.execute();
```

I got this in console.[image]

When I change the kafka source to  `KafkaSource<User>` and the deserializer to this  `.setValueOnlyDeserializer(AvroDeserializationSchema.forSpecific(User.class))`, I got this in console `{"name": "", "age": 0}`.

User class is the class generated by `avro-maven-plugin` from the avro schema I put in the command to send message to kafka.

Do you guys have any idea about this? A sample code that works does help a lot. I can not find any up-to-date sample. Thank you.

Comment: You need to use `ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema` if you're using the Schema Registry and Avro. `SimpleStringSchema` cannot read Avro

Answer (score 1):

In the end, what I need to do will be using `ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema` like this

```
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setParallelism(1);
    KafkaSource<User> source  = KafkaSource.<User>builder()
            .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
            .setTopics("test")
            .setGroupId("console-consumer-29300")
            .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
            .setValueOnlyDeserializer(ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.forSpecific(User.class, "http://localhost:8081"))
            .build();
    env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "kafka").print();
    env.execute();
```

I need to specify the link to schema registry and the class generated from avro schema. It won't work without url to schema registry

Anw, thank @OneCricketeer for the guide.

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleStringSchema` cannot read Avro, so your terminal is outputting decoded UTF-8 nonsense.

`AvroDeserializationSchema` may parse the bytes, but doesn't know anything about the schema in the Registry to do it properly.

`ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema` is what you want. For examples, [look at the test code](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-formats/flink-avro-confluent-registry/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/formats/avro/registry/confluent)

Comment: Thank for your help. But using `ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema` give me the same result as `AvroDeserializationSchema` Am i missing something?

Comment: Looks like you found the solution? Yes, you'll need to specific the registry address